# Grails 2.1.0, Spring Security Core - SpringSecurityUtils No Such Property

Tags: grails, spring-security, multi-tenant

I have a grails 2.1.0 application with Spring Security Core and Multi-tenant single db plugin working fine. One of the requirements for this application is to limit concurrent logins to just one. For this, I'm trying to use SpringSecurityUtils in Bootstrap to register a filter.

```
 SpringSecurityUtils.clientRegisterFilter('concurrencyFilter', SecurityFilterPosition.CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER)
```

SpringSecurityUtils is static and as the documentation says, need not be injected, but on executing, it errors out

```
ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: No such property: SpringSecurityUtils for class: BootStrap
```

Message: No such property: SpringSecurityUtils for class: BootStrap
   Line | Method
->>  17 | doCall                           in BootStrap$_closure1

---

|   301 | evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock in grails.util.Environment
|   294 | executeForEnvironment . . . . .  in     ''
|   270 | executeForCurrentEnvironment     in     ''
|   303 | innerRun . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run                              in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run                              in     ''
^   662 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread

Spring security is otherwise working fine.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the import - add

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils
```

and it looks like you'll need this too:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SecurityFilterPosition
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Burt. No Luck. I've tried import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils as well but no luck. I'm totally out of ideas at this time.

Comment: If its of any help, I have my User Domains and controllers in a plugin which is linked with my application. Now SpringSecurityUtils is working fine in the Logincontroller in the included plugin. It seems spring security core is not available in the application even though I have put in a compile time dependency as compile ':spring-security-core:1.2.7.3' in the plugins section is buildconfig.

Comment: This is crazy. Netbeans was acting up. I just restarted my IDE and everything started working. It was  import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils

Comment: As of 25/11/2016 the imports to be added are

import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SecurityFilterPosition

Answer (score 1):

@Burt Beckwith Answer is correct
As of 25-Nov-2016 the imports to be added are

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SecurityFilterPosition
```